# I cannot get my traffic light sequence to work in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, traffic

In my a452 computing class, I am trying to change an image with a button to represent I traffic light sequence.

I can display my first picture but the pictures will not change. in my sequence I have the pictures of the traffic lights but they cannot be displayed.

when I run it the first picture is loaded but then it will not load any other images

In my a452 computing I am trying to change an image with a button to represent I traffic light sequence. I can display my first picture but the pictures will not change, please help. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body> 
       <script> 
         var TLassets = ["Red.png","Redamber.png","Green.png","Amber.png"] 
         var count=0 
         function TL(){
          if(count<3){
            count=count+1
            document.getElemenybyId('lights').src=TLassets[count]; 
          }else{ 
            count=0 
            document.getElemenybyId('lights').src=TLassets[count]; 
          } 
        </script> 
        <center>
          <img id="lights" src='Red.png' ;>
        </center> 
        <center>
          <input type="button" id="change" value="change lights" onclick=TL()>
        </center> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var TLassets = ["Red.png","Redamber.png","Green.png","Amber.png"]
var count=0
function TL(){
 if(count<3){
  count=count+1
  document.getElemenybyId('lights').src=TLassets[count];
 }else{
  count=0
  document.getElemenybyId('lights').src=TLassets[count];
  }
</script>
<center><img id="lights" src='Red.png' ;></center>
<center><input type="button" id="change" value="change lights" onclick=TL()></center>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case sensitive problem: document.getElement**B**yId('lights'); (notice the bold letter, capitalize 'b').

I'd recommend splitting your code in "steps" if you're new. I made some modifications, check it out, it works for me. I added console-printing to clarify.

```
    <script>
    var count = 0;
    function TL() {
      var TLassets = ["Red.png", "yellow.png", "Green.png"];
      count++
        if (count < 3) {
          console.log(count);
          console.log(TLassets[count])
          var edit_picture =  document.getElementById('lights');
          edit_picture.src = TLassets[count];
        } else {
          count = 0;
          console.log(count);
          console.log(TLassets[count])
          var edit_picture =  document.getElementById('lights');
          edit_picture.src = TLassets[count];
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your code, check the console!
Once you fix them, the script works: `getElemenybyId` is not correct.